# The boundary of a tetrahedron minus one facet is homeomorphic to a triangle

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am really struggling with how to show this, I have found a geometric simplicial complex that has a tetrahedron minus one facet as the underlying space, and also one for the triangle. But I am confused where to go from there.

Comment: I would take a different approach.  If it's an equilateral tetrahedron, then the map that associates each point in the upper surface with its orthogonal projection on the base is clearly a bicontinuous bijection, and I'd try to modify this to the general case using a linear transformation.  Just an idea.

Comment: The thing is, it's for a project that is mainly about simplicial complexes and homology, so I think this is the way my supervisor is wanting me to go.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right in that case.  It's been way too long since I studied that stuff for me to have any ideas on it, though.

Comment: Note that the tetrahedron's boundary, minus its base, has a unique point in every verical line. So the projection to the base (by forgetting the height) is a piecewise linear homeomorphism. The base is a triangle.